# Western Digital PCB swap: What codes matter?

Tags: hard-drive, repair, wd

I read all about it here but am confused slightly

https://www.effectiveelectronics.com/blog/western-digital-hard-drive-pcb-swapping-replacement-guide/

I have a WD2500JB-00GVC0

This site says the DCM doesn't matter, at all. But there is a little code on the underside which is quite long.

Mine is:
2061-701265-200 AH --- XC 1X47 4PZ3 5 0001070 --- 6071

The part I'm confused about is that the website says "(2061-701267-200 AK). It is a “MUST” that you match the 2 letters following this number set or you will not have success with a simple PCB swap." Are they saying the 2 letters after just the number? or the 2 letters that appear after the code they've put. In my number, would they be referring to the "AH" or the "XC" being the extremely important letters?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.donordrives.com/pcb-replacement-guide) first.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.hddzone.com/hard_drive_pcb_replacement.html

> If the PCB is Western Digital PCB, you must match the Board Number on
> the back of the PCB, as the below picture:
>
> [image]
>
> The "PCB Number" is 2060-701537-003, to find a matching replacement
> PCB for WD HDD, we should make sure the "PCB Number" is the same.

In general swapping boards in DIY scenarios only makes sense if the drive does not spin at all.